# Design pattern for self-registering components/plugins

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have singleton class `World`. (It isn't required to be singleton, but nonetheless it is defined so in my project.)

Then I have `Component` interface, which is then implemented by `ConcreteComponent1`, `ConcreteComponent2` etc. These all implement some nice methods like `decorateTheWorld`.

At some point, the `World` instance would then iterate through all its children `Compontent`s and ask them to decorate itself by calling `decorateTheWorld` on them.

The problem with this approach is that the `World`, or something outside the `World` would then need to know about any kind of `Component` the `World` can have, since `Component` instances need to be created at some point, somehow.

The point is I don't want to make silly things like 100 lines of some repetetive code like

```
(new ConcreteComponent1())->registerInTheWorld()
(new ConcreteComponent2())->registerInTheWorld()
(new ConcreteComponent3())->registerInTheWorld()
```

...and I **don't** want to resort to reflection.

So, is there any design pattern that would make the registration part automatically, out of the box? Or am I asking for impossible?

Comment: You might get more views if you tagged this question with the language you are using.

Comment: What about the observer pattern, and adding the ConcreteComponent to World in the constructor?

Comment: @BjørnBråthen that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why is that actually? It fixes your registerInTheWorld problem, and you could easily iterate through your components and call decorateTheWorld on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that the components implemented a common interface, your world doesn't have to know about concrete components, just the interface.

See this example (C#):

```
public interface IComponent
{
    void decorateTheWorld();
}

public class ComponentA : IComponent
{
    public void decorateTheWorld() { /* ... */ }
}

public class ComponentB : IComponent { /* ... */ }
```

In your World class, assuming `_components` is a collection of `IComponent`s:

```
foreach(IComponent comp in _components)
    comp.decorateTheWorld();
```

Now, if you don't want to manually "find" the components, you could get all types from the assemblies you have loaded and find the ones that implement `IComponent` and then instantiate them using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: The point is that I have to manually create the `_components` collection and I'd like to let it create itself somehow as soon as assembly is loaded.

Comment: @rr. please see edit.  I know you say you do not want to resort to reflection, but you're going to have to do this some way.  What's so bad with resorting to reflection anyway?

Comment: @rr- Then use a IOC container and register your components via an xml file or whatever. your program cant guess how the class need to be built unless you tell it how to do so , especially when you dont even want to use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Since World is singleton i suggest World will hold a Set of Component and any Component in there constructor will be registered in the singleton.
so the singleton will iterate them without knowing there subtypes

Answer (score 0):

I made this approach, when having a simliar problem, shown below:

Make an Array of all the Components (not as the concrete implementation).

```
Array<Components> componentsAttributeInWorld
```

Then use creating methods you make yourself to create one or more Components at once. Use the for iteration method to create many at once

```
void createObjectType:(String)nameOfConcreteObjectClass AndCount:(int)numberOfObjects {
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfObjects; i++) {
        Component *comp = [[Class getClassWithName:nameOfConcreteObjectClass] new];
        [componentsAttributeInWorld addObject:comp];
    }
}
```

After that the objects are in the Array/List and your can iterate over them again with foreach again. In Objective-C you can dynamically test which class the Component really is and then do some special methods specific for that concrete implementation if you want. In Java you could even use switch for Strings.

```
…
for (Component *c in componentsAttributeInWorld) {
    if ([c isClass:@"ConcreteComponent1"]) {
        c.color = ccRED;
    else if ([c isClass:@"ConcreteComponent2"]) {
        c.size = ccsize(1,2,1);
    }
}
…
```

So you only have to handle the array and then the ordering is not relevant (I used it to know which object is the oldest one), then you can use a set which may be faster!